# toggle change nested button colors in ionic 2x

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I'm having nested button assigned in each list. What i want to achieve is when a particular button is clicked its color is suppose to change to a different color and when its clicked again is should revert back to the default color

```ts
setColor($event,item){
  if(item.colorVariable='light'){
    item.colorVariable='keep'
  } else {
    if(item.colorVariable='keep'){
      item.colorVariable='light'
    }
  }
}
```

HTML

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of searchResults">
  <ion-avatar item-start>
    <img  src="{{item.fb_pic}}">
  </ion-avatar>
  <h2>{{item.fname}}</h2>
  <button ion-button icon-start clear item-end (click)="setColor($event,item);" name="add-circle" [color]="item.colorVariable">
    <ion-icon name="navigate"></ion-icon>
    Like this
  </button>  
</ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not working because of your `setColor` method, there's a typo in your `if` statemente, to compare it should be `==` or `===` (you can search about the differences) and not `=`, so:

```
setColor($event,item){
  if(item.colorVariable == 'light'){
    item.colorVariable='keep'
  } else {
    if(item.colorVariable == 'keep'){
      item.colorVariable='light'
    }
  }
}
```

Also you don't need another if inside else, since it can have just 2 values for the colorVariable you can use:

```
setColor($event,item){
  if(item.colorVariable='light'){
    item.colorVariable='keep'
  } else {
    item.colorVariable='light'
  }
}
```

Want an even better solution? You can execute any one line code inside the click, so maybe you can eliminate the `setColor` method and use a ternary operator like this:

```
<button ion-button icon-start clear item-end (click)="item.colorVariable = item.colorVariable == 'light' ? 'keep' : 'light'" name="add-circle" [color]="item.colorVariable">
  <ion-icon name="navigate"></ion-icon>
    Like this
</button>
```

Ternary operator is like and easy inline if/else, you can do it in your `setColor` if you don't want to let this code in your button

```
setColor($event,item){
  item.colorVariable = item.colorVariable == 'light' ? 'keep' : 'light';
}
```

Hope this helps.